# Slate Docs function to keep navigation accordion open when clicking on other links in sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

For UX, there may be times where multiple sections need to be open at once in the sidebar. Currently, when another section header is clicked in the sidebar, other sections collapse. How do i make it so the all the sections are open and close only when i click on the section header itself

[image]

[image]

This is the code that handles this:

var $best = $toc.find("[href='" + best + "']").first();

```
  if (!$best.hasClass("active")) {
    // .active is applied to the ToC link we're currently on, and its parent <ul>s selected by tocListSelector
    // .active-expanded is applied to the ToC links that are parents of this one
    $toc.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $toc.find(".active-parent").removeClass("active-parent");
    $best.addClass("active");
    $best
      .parents(tocListSelector)
      .addClass("active")
      .siblings(tocLinkSelector)
      .addClass("active-parent");
    $best.siblings(tocListSelector).addClass("active");
    $toc.find(tocListSelector).filter(":not(.active)").slideUp(150);
    $toc.find(tocListSelector).filter(".active").slideDown(150);
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
      window.history.replaceState(null, "", best);
    }
    var thisTitle = $best.data("title");
    if (thisTitle !== undefined && thisTitle.length > 0) {
      document.title =
        thisTitle.replace(htmlPattern, "") + " – " + originalTitle;
    } else {
      document.title = originalTitle;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? It would be nice to post some code

Comment: So far i can disable the expanding of menus and make it so all the menus remain open when i click another menu but i am not able to close the menus on clicking on their parent

Answer (score 0):

The 2 following lines are where the previously selected section is closed.

```
    $toc.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $toc.find(".active-parent").removeClass("active-parent");
```

Comment them out and every section will remind open.

EDIT: to be able to close the section when you click on it you need to replace `.addClass` method by `toggleClass` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass). This way the `active` class is added if not present and remove in the opposite case.

Comment: I did this but there is no way to close them again. I'm not able to implement the function to close the section when you click on the header